# flutter scrollview and SingleChildScrollView throws bottom overflow and is not scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, singlechildscrollview

The widgets inside the child scroll view doesn't scroll and throws bottom overflow exception on the screen when there are more widgets in that list view. I am not sure where I am doing a mistake.

```
home: Scaffold(
      body: Column(
          children: [
              APPbar(),
              Container(
                 color: Colors.grey[200],
                 child: Expanded(
                     child: Column(
                         children: [
                            searchBar(),
                            Row(children: casewidgets),
                         ], 
                     )
                 ),
              )
            
             SingleChildScrollView(
                child:Column(
                   children: [
                       Text("a new column"),
                       Text("a new column"),
                       Text("a new column"),
                       Text("a new column"),
                   ],
               )
             ),
        ]
)),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Expanded` on SingleChildScollView to get aviable height, and remove column's Expanded.

```dart
home: Scaffold(
    body: Column(children: [
  // APPbar(),
  Container(
    color: Colors.grey[200],
    child: Column(
      children: [
        // searchBar(),
        Row(children: []),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  Expanded(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++) Text("a new column"),
      ],
    )),
  ),
])),
```

Comment: perfect. Didn't know that C syntax will work inside a widget. First day in flutter.

Comment: you mean looping, you can think  as expression, it returns single item on every loop, forgot the exact name, btw there are many  action can be perform like this, find more on inline function/ anonymous function

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use expand when using a singlechildscrollview **in appropriate way**. First you need to understand that expand covers the maximum height and width on the screen or the specific section in which you use expand.

Instead of using `SingleChildScrollView`, It's easier to use `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverFillRemaining`. and it's works work's great.

```
    CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverFillRemaining(
                hasScrollBody: false,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Text('TextData'),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: Text("Your Text Data",),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Text('Add Other Widgets'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```